# Pulumi GCP Manage Oauth2.0 Client Id Redirect URI

Tags: google-cloud-platform, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, pulumi

In GCP, there is a resource called “APIs and Services” available under https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials

I want to be able to manage the OAuth2.0 Client here as a Pulumi resource. The screenshot below might help:

Any thoughts?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this is not possible. Google [does not offer an API](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35907249) to programmatically create or update OAuth 2.0 Clients, subsequently, Pulumi can't offer this functionality either.